# How to define custom filter to block spam in Drupal

Tags: regex, drupal

Drupal has a nice [spam module](http://drupal.org/project/spam) with a lot of features, including defining Custom filters. The filters can be either Plain text or Regular expressions. I am a bit familiar with regexp but not sure how to define regexps in spam module in order to block any occurrences of spam strings like

myblablaviagra.com

or phone numbers like:

091234567

The thing that I am really not sure of is that whether the regex need to be enclosed in '/ /' or something else. Unfortunately I could not find any examples of custom regex filter in action, hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the docs](http://drupal.org/node/498092#custom), you can define a literal string that is matched "verbatim" using quotes `'myblablaviagra.com'`, or a regex using delimiters `/^\d+$/` (standard Perl re syntax).